# Downloading Documents via .Net web api from azure blob

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, azure-blob-storage

I having a tough time figuring out what is going wrong. My app hits the api to fetch a document. What is happening is the download starts,but hangs. Eventually it will finish (either with an error or completely), but when I attempt to open say a pdf, I get a "cannot open pdf" or something along those lines. It works locally.

my controller:

```
 [Route("api/listing/attachment")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAttachmentAsync(string fileName)
    {
        var attachment = await _repository.GetAttachmentAsync(fileName);
        var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.ContentType = "application/x-download";
        var removePath = fileName.Substring(fileName.IndexOf("/", fileName.IndexOf("/", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1, StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1);
        response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", removePath));
        response.AddHeader("content-length", attachment.Length.ToString());
        response.BinaryWrite(attachment);
        response.Flush();
        return null;
    }
```

my repository:

```
public async Task<byte[]> GetAttachmentAsync(string fileName)
    {
        var container = _blobClient.GetContainerReference(_containerName);
        var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're not returning any response back... you should return something that implements `IHttpActionResult`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing your controller code to:

```
[Route("api/listing/attachment")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAttachmentAsync(string fileName)
{
    var attachment = await _repository.GetAttachmentAsync(fileName);
    var removePath = fileName.Substring(fileName.IndexOf("/", fileName.IndexOf("/", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1, StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1);

    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new ByteArrayContent(attachment)
    };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = removePath
    };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I made one change to your code and it worked perfectly. I changed the signature to  `public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAttachmentAsync(string fileName)`

I can't upvote you,but this was what I needed. Thank you so much